# Why isn't 03 bigger than 00?

Tags: php

With this IF statement:

```
 if ( (date('i')>=00) && (date('i')<=19) ) {
     $a=1;
 }

 if ( (date('i')>=20) && (date('i')<=39) ) {
     $a=2;
 }

 if ( (date('i')>=40) && (date('i')<=59) ) {
     $a=3;
 } else {
     $a=0;
 }
```

When `date('i')` is for example "03", I'm getting `a=0` instead of `a=1`.

Shouldn't 03 be considered bigger than 00?

What's the best way to achieve what I want here?

Comment: You're comparing strings to integers.

Comment: @ʰᵈˑ I'm working with minutes here, not day of the month...

Comment: Just cast it: `(int) date('i')`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what should I do then? It works fine when `date('i') = 52` for example, then I'm getting `a=3` as I expect.

Comment: should I be using `==` somewhere here?

Comment: @rockyraw no, he's misunderstood you again :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's got nothing to do with variable types.

The last if statement makes your first two irrelevant. `$a` will only ever be either `3` or `0`. You need `else if`.

Also, assign `date('i')` to a variable to avoid calling it constantly.

```
$d = date('i');

if ($d >= 00 && $d <= 19) {
    $a = 1;
}
else if ($d >= 20 && $d <= 39) {
    $a = 2;
}
else if ($d >= 40 && $d <= 59) {
    $a = 3;
} else {
    $a = 0;
}
```

Or, to make things neater:

```
$d = date('i');
$a = 0;

if($d >= 00) $a = 1;
if($d >= 20) $a = 2;
if($d >= 40) $a = 3;
```

Comment: A good catch. PHP automatically converts numeric strings to integers for comparison, so his types are fine. Well spotted :-)

Comment: OMG. I'm staying away from PHP :)

Answer (score 0):

In PHP the function date() return a string, so the best way to compare date with integer is to do the casting.
Try with this syntaxe : `if((int)date('i') > 0 && (int)date('i') <= 19) { $a = 1; }`

Best Regards,
Anis