# Time related If conditions don't work correctly

Tags: php

I have these conditions:

```
$year = date('Y');
$month = date('M');
$day = date('j');
$hour = date('H');

if($hour >= 00) $a = 05;
if($hour >= 04) $a = 09;
if($hour >= 08) $a = 13;
if($hour >= 12) $a = 17;
if($hour >= 16) $a = 21;
if($hour >= 20) $a = 01;
```

which should mean that if the current server time is 4:10AM for example,
then `a` value **should be** `09`.

yet when I run a test and echo `a`, the value is `13`.

Here'w what I'm echoing:

```
<?php 
$now = new DateTime(); 
echo $now->format("M j, Y H:i:s O")."\n"; 
?>

<p>
<?php echo $a ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php echo $month ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php echo $year ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php echo $day ?>
</p>
<p>
<?php echo $hour ?>
</p>
```

and the results:

```
Oct 25, 2014 04:59:55 -0400
13
Oct
2014
25
04
```

Comment: @C4ud3x If he does that, he needs to reverse their order. If the current hour is 21, `$hour >= 0` will be true.

Comment: the current format worked perfect [in a similar case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26138939/why-isnt-03-bigger-than-00), see the edited answer that allowed using `if` only.

Comment: But in that case he is using a range of values given a `min` and `max`

Comment: where do you see a `min ` and `max`? I'm talking about the part of the answer that start with `Or, to make things neater:`

Comment: Each `date` call yields a potentially separate time, separated by seconds depending upon time slicing.  Starting numbers with `0` signals to PHP you're using octal.

Comment: use G , to avoid leading zeroes . 
echo $now->format("M j, Y G:i:s O")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the leading zeroes on your numbers. When a number begins with `0`, it's interpreted as octal. But octal doesn't have digits `8` and `9`, so the number parser stops at those characters, and interprets `08` and `09` as `0`. So the line:

```
if ($hour >= 08) $a = 13;
```

is treated as if you'd written:

```
if ($hour >= 0) $a = 13;
```

Since `4 >= 0` is true, it sets `$a` to `13`.

Actually, since you're dealing with strings, the correct thing to do is use string comparisons:

```
if ($hour >= '20') $a = '01';
elseif ($hour >= '16') $a = '21';
elseif ($hour >= '12') $a = 17;
...
```

Comment: should I get rid of them only in the `$hour` part, or also in the `$a` part? also, since `$hour` is based on `$hour = date('H');` wouldn't there be any problem? as `H` always has leading zeroes.

Comment: You'd need to do it in both places. `$a = 09;` is treated as `$a = 0;`. And you should use `date('G')` to get numbers without leading zeroes. Or you could do what I just added to my answer: use strings everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Extending @Barmars answer ,

even

```
if(09 < "09")
   {
     echo "yes";
   }
   else
   {
     echo "false";
   }
```

will echo `yes`

use format character `G` , to avoid leading zeroes .

```
echo $now->format("M j, Y G:i:s O")
```

and then compare.